# C# Clipboard and DataObject not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, clipboard, copy-paste, idataobject

I'm trying to use the `Clipboard` to store selected objects in a program I've written, for the purposes of copy and paste (obviously). My copy code is:

```
DataObject oWrapper;

Clipboard.Clear();
oWrapper = new DataObject();
oWrapper.SetData(typeof(FormDesignerControls), this.SelectedControls.Clone());
Clipboard.SetDataObject(oWrapper, false);
```

And my paste code, so far, is:

```
DataObject oWrapper;

oWrapper = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (oWrapper.GetDataPresent(typeof(FormDesignerControls)))
{
    oFDCs = (FormDesignerControls)oWrapper.GetData(typeof(FormDesignerControls));
}
```

`FormDesignerControls` is a collection class which will contain the copied objects.

The copy code appears to work fine. When the paste code runs, the call to `oWrapper.GetDataPresent` returns `true` in the if conditional. However, the call to `oWrapper.GetData` returns `null`.

Am I missing a trick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register your type of data:

```c#
    private static readonly DataFormats.Format myDataClipboardFormat =
        DataFormats.GetFormat("myData");
```

Copy:

```c#
    MyDataType data = <your object>
    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(myDataClipboardFormat.Name, data);
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Paste:

```c#
    if (!Clipboard.ContainsData(myDataClipboardFormat.Name))
        return;
    IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (dataObject == null)
        return;
    MyDataTypedata = 
       (MyDataType)dataObject.GetData(myDataClipboardFormat.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Given that what I'm trying to store is an instance of a class, what should I supply to `DataFormats.GetFormat`? It appears to take an int or a string.

Comment: It's name of your format. In my example it's string "myData".